# Android Bluetooth Can't Connect using createRfcommSocketServiceRecord

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, connection

I already managed to get it working using this method at android 2.3.3 version, but now I am testing using another device with 2.2 version..
And I can find many devices using discovery, but can't connect to other devices using:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = deviceToConnect.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(MY_UUID));
```

On the other side, I am using the proper thread to accept the connection using :

```
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


    BluetoothServerSocket ss;
    try {

        ss = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(MainPage.SD_FolderName, UUID.fromString(MY_UUID));
        new Thread(new ListenerHandler(ss, this, resultCode)).start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There was a problem opening the bluetooth server socket!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
```

Then on the ListenerHandler I have this:

```
BluetoothSocket clientSocket = ss.accept();
```

But the connection is never stablished, any thoughs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: I can't test this at virtual device, because there is no bluetooth. How can I manage to get a logcat output on my phone?
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: but now I am testing using another device with 2.2 version.. what does it mean

Comment: With android 2.2 version I can't use createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, can't connect to device... I am using threads, the problem is that the connection just not connect